# Scala Option filter method doubts

Tags: scala, filter, scala-option

I have been reading through Scala docs and while skimming through `Option` class I saw `filter` implementation that looks like this:

```
final def filter(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = 
  if (isEmpty || p(this.get)) this else None
```

Why do we have to check whether our `Option` instance is empty? Wouldn't this result in `None` either way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `||` is short-circuiting, so checking `isEmpty` first ensures that `get` won't be called on an empty option (which would throw an exception).